# Как исправить ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: invalid data source name in?

Tags: php, база-данных, sqlite

Нужно подключится к базе данных sqlite. Выдает ошибку:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: invalid data source name in
>   W:\domains\testosite.ru\index.php:2 Stack trace: #0
>   W:\domains\testosite.ru\index.php(2): PDO->__construct('localhost') #1
>   {main} thrown in W:\domains\testosite.ru\index.php on line 2

Для подключения к базе выполняю следующие действия:

1. Создаю в папке `open server` каталог testosite.ru.
2. Создаю файл `index.php`.
3. Создаю папку data. Помещаю в нее adminer.
4. Вход в админер: выбираю движок - Sqlite3 и ввожу название создаваемой базы -
   `liga.db`.
   5.Создаю базу данных. В ней таблицу calendar. Заполняю данными. В папке data появляется файл `liga.db`. Открываю для проверки базу в админере - база создана и заполнена.
5. В `index.php` создаю подключение к базе:

```php
<?php

$dbh = new PDO ("data/liga.db"); 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM calendar;";
$res = $dbh->query($sql);

if($res){
   while ( ($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) !== false) {
      $result[] = $row;
   }
}

?>
```

В результате выдает вышеуказанную ошибку.
Подключаюсь к базе sqlite впервые.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы указали неправильный `data source name` (более известный как `DSN`). Для `sqlite`, [например](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php), корректным `DSN` будет:

```
sqlite:/opt/databases/mydb.sq3
```

Обязательное указание используемого драйвера, затем после двоеточия параметры этого драйвера. У драйвера `sqlite` опций всего ничего, либо указать путь к файлу базы либо указать, что база нужна временно в памяти и сохранять её не нужно. `localhost` указать конечно можно, но это будет расценено именно как имя файла. Потому что `sqlite` - это не клиент-серверная штука и никакого сетевого взаимодействия не подразумевает.

Comment: после изенения подключеняи на `$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:/data/liga.db");` выдает ошибку:
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in W:\domains\testosite.ru\index.php:3 Stack trace: #0 W:\domains\testosite.ru\index.php(3): PDO->__construct('sqlite:/data/li...') #1 {main} thrown in W:\domains\testosite.ru\index.php on line 3

Comment: Значит не может открыть такой файл. Попробуйте указать абсолютный путь. Не знаю, как windows обрабатывает unix пути начинающиеся с `/`.

Comment: абсолютный путь тоже ничего не изменил. Я уже несколько раз пересоздавал базу, переносил ее в другое место, но на данный момент выдает теперь просто пустую страницу. Вот текущий код: 
`<?php
$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:ligashl.db"); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 5;";
$res = $dbh->query($sql);
  if ($res){
        while (($row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) !== false) {
                $result[] = $row;
            echo '
            <p>'.$row[id].'</p>
            <p>'.$row[name_1].'</p>
            <p>'.$row[name_2].'</p>  
           ';
   };  
 };
?>`

Comment: Проблема решена: нужно было прописать `$dbh = new PDO("sqlite:data/ligashl.db");`. Пустой экран был из-за того что в строке `$sql = "SELECT * FROM WHERE id BETWEEN 1 and 5;";` была допущена ошибка - забыл указать название таблицы.